# Crear archivo txt en el servidor con php

Tags: php, servidor, archivo

Quiero crear un archivo txt con los datos que recibí de un formulario, al hacerlo de manera local sí funciona correctamente y hasta lo puedo descargar pero al probarlo en el servidor, no crea el archivo. He probado con lo siguiente:

Opción 1:

```
  //Guardar datos//
                  $datos = fopen("formato_ilustradores/datos_ilustradores.txt", "a");
                  fwrite($datos, "Folio: " . $aleatorio . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Titulo: " . $titulo . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Fecha: " . $fecha . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Tecnica: " . $tecnica . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Medidas Alto: " . $medidas_alto . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Medidas Base: " . $medidas_base . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Seudonimo: " . $seudonimo . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Edad: " . $edad . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Ciudad: " . $ciudad . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Telefono: " . $telefono . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Celular: " . $celular . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Correo: " . $correo . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Sitio: " . $sitio . "\n \n");

                  fclose($datos);
                    */
```

Opción 2:

```
                    /*
                  $archivo = "datos_ilustradores.txt";
                  $ruta = "formato_ilustradores/$archivo";
                  $crea = fopen($ruta, "w");
                  fwrite($crea, $titulo);
                  fclose($crea);
                  */
```

Pero ninguna funciona. ¿Alguna idea de que puede estar mal? ¿O algún otro método?

Answer (score 1):

Si «formato_ilustradores» es una carpeta **existente** que está en el mismo directorio que el archivo .php que contiene ese código, puedes anteponer un punto y un slash a la ruta:

```
$datos = fopen("./formato_ilustradores/datos_ilustradores.txt", "a");
```

Si el directorio no existe, debes crearlo.

Comment: Sí, es una carpeta y lo puse como lo indicaste y tampoco funciona. Cree el archivo manualmente dentro del servidor, y sí lo lee pero no escribe nada en el. ¿Alguna otra recomendación?

Answer (score 1):

Por que no usas esto pruebalo

```
                $data .= str_pad(trim($tudata),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                $data .= str_pad(trim($tudata),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                $data .= str_pad(trim($tudata),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                $data .= str_pad(trim($tudata),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                $data .= str_pad(trim($tudata),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $nombre = "nombreArchivo.txt";
        $file = fopen("../../RutaArchivo/" . $nombre, "w+");
        $check = chmod("../../RutaArchivo/" . $nombre, 0777);

        fwrite($file, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes primero preguntar si puedes escribir en el directorio

```
is_writable($pathToDir);
```

Y luego guardar el archivo

```
fopen($filepath, 'w+');
```